# Memory leak when using CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using a `NSMutableArray` to hold `CLLocationCoordinate2D` values. After testing for a few mins I found the app crashing. I found heavy memory leaks associated with both the array and `CLLocationCoordinate2D` values.

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayReturn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D obj1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.6085289,107.5941445);
CLLocationCoordinate2D obj2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.1727738,78.041655);

[arrayReturn addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&obj1  objCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)]];
[arrayReturn addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&obj2 objCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)]];

return [arrayReturn autorelease];
```

I am creating several objects like this and adding it to the array. Even though I have tagged an autorelease at the end, I have heavy memory leaks in the array.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How does your app crash? Where does it crash? How have you determined that you have memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

A CLLocationCoordinate2D is a simple struct of 2 double values and not an NSObject!

You allocate the CLLocationCoordinate2D on the stack and pass pointers to that data in the NSValue objects. But the stack memory will be not available after the method returns. This is why your app crashes.

You need to convert the CLLocationCoordinate2D into NSObjects somehow.
For example like this:

```
NSArray* coords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:obj1.latitude], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:obj1.longitude], nil];
```

Comment: valueWithBytes:objCType: creates an NSValue object that contains a copy of the contents that were passed into it and information on how that is encoded.   The point of this routine is to do exactly what he is trying to do, convert CLLocationCordinate2D into an NSValue, which is an NSObject subclass and can be put into an NSArray without difficulty.

Comment: Should i use free to release each of those CLLocationCoordinate2D addresses??

Comment: Also is there any other alternative of adding CLLocationCoordinate in an array so that i can get around this issue..

Comment: you could use a simple C-Array